# DNS routing for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns

Basecamp-like subdomains use to be so in-style. :) Well I would like to create an app that has a premium feature allowing users to point their domain names to the app and have the app resolve (A record or CNAME) to their customized view just like folks use to do with Basecamp-like subdomains.  I want a programmatic way without restarting web servers or using AWS; something entirely controlled by my Rails app. If it involves zone files, I would want some programmatic way of controlling them.

**Edit**
To be clear, I am not looking for subdomain customization.  I want my app to offer allowing one to point their domain names to my app.  So customerurl.com points to a whitelabeled version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `request` object and query the `subdomain` key. Use that to do whatever customization you need in your app. Maybe a before filter defined in your application controller?

ETA: The same strategy obtains even if it queries a different part of the `request` object. e.g.

```
def do_customizations
  if request.host == 'example.com'
    # Do customization for example.com
    # Might need more sophisticated matching to deal with presence/absence 
    # of 'www' or other subdomains
  elsif request.host == 'main-domain.com'
    # Maybe you want a more sophisticated test than if/else/else, but that's OK
  else
    # Default settings
  end
end
```

and then, in your controller(s),

```
before_filter :do_customizations
```